# How to disable change password option for other users?

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I want to prevent the user from changing other users' passwords, so he can only change his own password

Answer (score 1):

You need to do it in following way:

- Create a security group. With this group of users, allow them to change passwords.
- There are two ways to change passwords. One from the "Change Password" button in user form view and from the Action > Change Password. Both options are available from the Users form/tree view.
- Inherit user form view and wizard action, provide groups which we have created in the first step.
- Upgrade your module. Login with and without a special security group and you will notice that Change Password is only visible for special users who have security groups turned on.

Comment: Hello @bhavesh with this approach, anyone can change the other user PWD (if I've allowed that grp).isisn't it? can we use here Record Rule or if not RR then on change pwd   check the validation with matching current user domain ?

Comment: Yes, with this approach, can change password of others. If you are planning to implement, user can change only own password. Then develop small boolean function, decide to visible/disable.